# NavigationManager - Get current URL in a Blazor component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I need to know the URL of the current page in order to check if I have to apply a certain style to an element. The code below is an example.

```html
    @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Services
    @inject IUriHelper UriHelper
    @implements IDisposable

    <h1>@url</h1>
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Blazor</a>
            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li>
                    <NavLink href="/" Match=NavLinkMatch.All>
                        Home
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <NavLink href="/counter">
                        Counter
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <NavLink href="/fetchdata">
                        Fetch data
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    @functions {

        private string url = string.Empty;

        protected override void OnInit()
        {
            url = UriHelper.GetAbsoluteUri();
            UriHelper.OnLocationChanged += OnLocationChanged;
        }

        private void OnLocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            url = newUriAbsolute;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            UriHelper.OnLocationChanged -= OnLocationChanged;
        }
    }
```

I used the same approach used in the NavLink component in the Blazor repository, but it did not work. Any ideas?.

Comment: GetAbsoluteUri() works for me, what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 238):

Use the **`Uri`** property from the **`NavigationManager`** class.

#### How it works

Get it from injection before using it on `.razor` pages:

```
@inject NavigationManager MyNavigationManager
```

Or like this in a `.cs` file if you prefer the "code-behind" experience:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
// ...
[Inject]
public NavigationManager MyNavigationManager {get; set;} = default!;
```

#### Sample

```
@page "/navigate"
@inject NavigationManager MyNavigationManager

<h1>Current URL</h1>

<p>@(MyNavigationManager.Uri)</p>
```

*More about navigation (NavigateTo, BaseUri, ToAbsoluteUri, ToBaseRelativePath, ... ) at: [URI and navigation state helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.0#uri-and-navigation-state-helpers)*

#### NavigationManager cheatsheet

```
MyNavigationManager.Uri
#> https://localhost:5001/counter/3?q=hi

MyNavigationManager.BaseUri
#> https://localhost:5001/

MyNavigationManager.NavigateTo("http://new location")
#> Navigates to new location

MyNavigationManager.LocationChanged
#> An event that fires when the navigation location has changed.

MyNavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("pepe")
#> https://localhost:5001/pepe

MyNavigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(MyNavigationManager.Uri)
#> counter/3?q=hi

Helper: AddQueryParm( "q2", "bye" ) // (*1)
#> https://localhost:5001/counter/3?q=hi&q2=bye

Helper: GetQueryParm( "q" )
#> hi
```

`(*1)` Net6 introduces `GetUriWithQueryParameter`. More info: [Manipulate the query string from Blazor](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-rc-1/#manipulate-the-query-string-from-blazor)

Helpers code:

```
@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    // Blazor: add parm to URL
    string AddQueryParm(string parmName, string parmValue)
    {
        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(MyNavigationManager.Uri);
        var q = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
        q[parmName] = parmValue;
        uriBuilder.Query = q.ToString();
        var newUrl = uriBuilder.ToString();
        return newUrl;
    }

    // Blazor: get query parm from the URL
    string GetQueryParm(string parmName)
    {
        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(MyNavigationManager.Uri);
        var q = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
        return q[parmName] ?? "";
    }

}
```

Comment: starting with v0.8.0 when using server side mode you should use:

`@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Services.IUriHelper UriHelper` 

and when using client-side mode:

`@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Services.WebAssemblyUriHelper UriHelper`

Comment: @ Henry Rodriguez, no, you're wrong. The correct way is to inject IUriHelper, not the implementation..

Comment: It's not working if usert try to force to another page over the Url address

Comment: The cheatsheet is very helpful +1

Comment: Cheatsheet `GetQueryParam` only works with query parameters, how would you get route parameters?

Comment: Full documented ad [route parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#route-parameters)

Answer (score 11):

First of all, inject `NavigationManager` into the component in which you need to get the current URL  as below:

```
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
```

Now use the below line to get the current URL:

```
string Url = NavManager.Uri.ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no use in connecting to the `OnLocationChanged` event in a page or component, as they get loaded and disposed on demand.

You should register to this event in app.cshtml as that won't be disposed.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I only needed the Uri of the page and not the base Uri aswell.

I keep all my code in a razor.cs file so I inject NavigationManager from code-behind like this:

```
[Inject] public NavigationManager Navigation { get; set; }
```

Navigation.Uri yeilds:
https://localhost:5001/nail-square-singel-shear-timber-timber

So to get the page Uri just do like this:

```
Navigation.Uri.Replace(Navigation.BaseUri,"")
```

The above yields:
nail-square-singel-shear-timber-timber

Comment: This is the purpose of the method `NavigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(string uri)`.

Answer (score 3):

You should listen to a LocationChange of the IUriHelper, which triggers the function to do what you want for example:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Components
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Services.IUriHelper UriHelper
@inject ILogger<NavItem> logger

<li class="m-menu__item @(Active ? "m-menu__item--active" : "")">
    <a href=@Url class="m-menu__link ">
        <span class="m-menu__item-here"></span>
        <i class="m-menu__link-icon @Icon"></i>
        <span class="m-menu__link-text">@Text</span>
    </a>
</li>

@functions {
    protected override void OnInit()
    {
        UriHelper.OnLocationChanged += OnLocationChanges;
    }
    [Parameter]
    private string Url { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    private string Icon { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    private string Text { get; set; }
    private bool Active = false;
    private void OnLocationChanges(object sender, string newLocation)
    {
        bool active = newLocation.Contains(Url);
        if(active != Active) //Only re-render the components that need it
        {
            Active = active;
            StateHasChanged();
            logger.LogInformation("Location Change To:" + newLocation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This UriHelper.OnLocationChanged event has new parameters that were causing an error with this example with .netCore 3 preview6. Should be:   private void OnLocationChanges(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)

Comment: this answer was for an out-dated version of blazor, use NavigationManager  now.

Answer (score 3):

Create somewhere an extension method like this:

```cs
namespace YourSolution.YourProject
{
    public static class NavigationManagerExtention
    {
        public static string Page(this NavigationManager navigation)
        {
            return navigation.Uri.Substring(navigation.BaseUri.Length - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

and to get the page part of URL just call `_nav.Page()`

Examples:

- For `example.com/home` it returns `/home`
- For `example.com/` it returns `/`

If you don't need a slash char (`/`) replace

```cs
return navigation.Uri.Substring(navigation.BaseUri.Length - 1);
```

with

```cs
return navigation.Uri.Substring(navigation.BaseUri.Length);
```