# C# Blazor client-side read hash parameters from url

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a project in [Blazor](https://blazor.net/)

And on the client-side, I want to read hash parameters

**I know how to do it in JavaScript - but my question is how to do it in c# client-side in Blazor project**

For example, I have an URL http://localhost:5060/#token=12345678

How to take `token`?

my code in index.cshtml

```
@page "/"
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Services.IUriHelper UriHelper

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

url is @Url

@functions {
protected override void OnInit() {
    Url = GetUrl();
}

public string Url { get; set; }

public string GetUrl() {
    return ?;
}
}
```

Comment: @DawidFerenczy Blazor is a experimental C# framework for Client Side scripting. using WebAssembly https://blazor.net/

Comment: Perhaps this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50102726/get-current-url-in-a-blazor-component

Comment: @elgonzo yes it works well. Thank you =)

Comment: By the way, perhaps you could change your URL to use "route parameters". This could perhaps make it easier to map the token to a component property (see here: https://codedaze.io/blazor-bites-routing/). Although, i have to admit i haven't done anything like that myself, so i might talk complete bollocks here ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current Url in a Blazor component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50102726/get-current-url-in-a-blazor-component)

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Did you try to read my question?! There is an answer in JS but I try to solve it in C#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can do it in JavaScript, then use JavaScript Interop: 
1. Define a JavaScript function which extract the token.
2. Define a C# method which call the function

But it would be still better to do that with Blazor which itself use JavaScript... 
What you need is to look at the methods defined in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Services.UriHelperBase and/or 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Browser.Services.BrowserUriHelper

Hope this helps...

Note: the `<base>` element is set in the Index.Html file located in the 
wwwroot folder.

> "The `HTML <base>` element specifies the base URL to use for all
>   relative URLs contained within a document. There can be only one
>    element in a document.
>
> The base URL of a document can be queried from a script using
>   document.baseURI."

Try this:

```
var absoluteUrl = UriHelper.GetAbsoluteUri();
var token = absoluteUrl.Substring(absoluteUrl.IndexOf("=") + 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

For reading hash parameters in C# Blazor without JavaScript or other client-side solutions I need to change function, like in the code below:

```
@functions {
  private string url = string.Empty;

  protected override void OnInit() {
    string url = UriHelper.GetAbsoluteUri();
    string[] parameters = url.Replace(UriHelper.GetBaseUri(), "").Replace("#", "").Split('&');

    string token = string.Empty;

    foreach (string prm in parameters) {
      if (prm.IndexOf("token=") >= 0) {
        token = prm.Replace("token=", "");
      }
    }

    UriHelper.OnLocationChanged += OnLocationChanged;
  }

  private void OnLocationChanged(object sender, string newUriAbsolute) {
    url = newUriAbsolute;
  }

  public void Dispose() {
    UriHelper.OnLocationChanged -= OnLocationChanged;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to retrieve the hash bookmark from a url in a Blazor component.  UriHelper was not available.  I had to use NavigationManager:

```
@inject NavigationManager _navigationManager;

.....
......

@code {
...
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
        var uri = _navigationManager.Uri;
        int si = uri.IndexOf("#model=");
        var modelFile = si > 0 ? uri.Substring(si + 7) : ""; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Uri.Fragment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.fragment) should do a trick, as well as [catch-all](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing#catch-all-route-parameters) page route parameter.

E.g. if the current URL is `https://my.site/my-page/#my-lovely-hash-link`

you should see `Current Fragment: #my-lovely-hash-link`

```
@page "/my-page/{*whatever}"
@inject NavigationManager Navigation

<div>
    Current Fragment: @CurrentFragment
    Also in: @Whatever
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string? Whatever { get; set; }
    private string CurrentFragment => new Uri(Navigation.Uri, UriKind.Absolute).Fragment;
}
```