# How to redirect to Blazor with token

Tags: cookies, middleware, blazor

I have a `Middleware` which performs an authentification and should then reroute to a `Blazor` web application.

The problem is that I get the `token` put in the request query and I want it in the body of the request.

Middleware:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context) {
    string token = context.Request.Query["token"];

    if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
         //do some logic to authenticate
    }
    else  
        await this.next(context);
}
```

Configure:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) 
{
    app.UseResponseCompression();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMiddleware<MultiAuthWare>();

    app.UseMvc(routes => {
                routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
    });

    app.UseBlazor<Client.Startup>();
}
```

Blazor entry point:

The server redirects to :  `http://localhost:[portno]/?token=[a string]` and I do not know why.Any who i have tried setting both routes for the entry page of `Blazor` and it does not load it.

```
@page "/"
@page "/?token={token}"
@inherits HomeBase
@functions()
{

}
```

**PS:** I do not understand why does the server put the `token` in the query string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) To retrieve `token` from get parameters you should to parse [current url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53448294/842935), you can do it in your `HomeBase`:

```
        var url = UriHelper.GetAbsoluteUri();  // By injection (see link)
        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(url);  // System namespace
        var q = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
        var token = q["token"];
```

2) I don't understand the second part of your question, when you talk about to  send token in body.

More info at [Get current Url in a Blazor component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50102726/get-current-url-in-a-blazor-component)