# How to inject IUriHelper service in Blazor?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

How to add implementation of `IUriHelper` service to Startup.cs in Blazor?

Comment: Are you talking about your own implementation?

Comment: No. When I'm using @Inject IUriHelper I'm getting InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'uriHelper' on type 'WebUI.Shared.NavMenu'. There is no registered service of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Services.IUriHelper'.

Comment: ok @sideCode, see my answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`IUriHelper` is now `NavigationManager`. [See Get current Url in a Blazor component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50102726/get-current-url-in-a-blazor-component) for details.

You can inject and use `NavigationManager` at `Shared/NavMenu.cshtml` without issues. You don't need any expecial, you don't need to add `NavigationManager` at app startup, it's already injected. Sample:

`Shared/NavMenu.cshtml:`

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<div class="top-row pl-4 navbar navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
        @(NavigationManager.Uri)    @* <--- sample using it --- *@
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]