# Blazor alternative to JS window.location.href

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Does anyone knows if there is any alternative to Javascripts **window.location.href()** to replace URL in users addressbar in Blazor server-side at any event (button click, etc)? Or I just have to use Blazor JavaScript interop and write JS directly?

Comment: What's question or issue here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The blazor way to change url (or navigate to another url) is using `NavigationManager`:

```
@inject NavigationManager MyNavigationManager
...
MyNavigationManager.NavigateTo("http://new location")
```

Learn how to inject navigation manager and how to use it at [NavigationManager cheatsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53448294/842935)

About to call it on events, this is a c# issue. Just subscribe to events and make `MyNavigationManager.NavigateTo` calls.

Comment: Thats it! When new location is the same as original @page route, Blazor won't refresh page as I was aware it'll do and just changes URL in addressbar!

Comment: Also, when new url goes to the same 'SPA', the page will not be reloaded.