# How to make NavLink with NavLinkMatch.All active with the hash sign at the end

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

Using server side Blazor I have a link to the main page in the navigation menu:

```
<NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">Main</NavLink>
```

With https://localhost it is active, with https://localhost/# it is not, while the app is still on the main page.
I can't use `NavLinkMatch.Prefix` as Main link will be active on every pages.

P.S. I'm using server side Blazor with Google OAuth2. After authentication Google redirects to the main page with # at the end. After this Main link becomes inactive.

Comment: Digging [NavLink NavLinkMatch.All code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Components/Web/src/Routing/NavLink.cs) I see it's not ready to deal with `#` ( only with the optional last `/` ). As workaround, on init, you can check for last `#` and redirect to the same page without `#`. I share here the [NavigationManager cheatsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53448294). Also you can write your own navlink.