# How can a Blazor server side app redirect from http://hostname to http://hostname/route1 on load?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-5, asp.net5

For several of the sites I have built using MVC/TypeScript or MVC/Angular I have needed to redirect the user immediately from http://hostname to http://hostname/route1.  I am trying to figure out how to implement the same functionality with Blazor Server Side.

I am aware that this can be done using the IIS URL Rewrite engine, however, it has not been determined if the application will be hosted under IIS, self-hosted on Windows, or hosted on Linux.

Is this possible? If so, what is the best practice approach for this implementation?

Thanks

Comment: You could redirect on the index components OnInitialized() method by calling an injected NavigationManager to redirect to your desired location.

Comment: Thus you're making the Index component useless as whenever the user tries to reach the Index page, he's automatically redirected to the desired location. This solution is rather impractical, no ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone.  You provided a starting point.

I changed MainLayout.razor to override the OnInitialized method.

```
@inject NavigationManager MyNavigationManager
@code
{
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var currentUri = new Uri(MyNavigationManager.Uri);
        if (currentUri.AbsolutePath == "/")
                MyNavigationManager.NavigateTo("route1");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a redirect on `OnInitialize` on your root page (maybe `index.razor` )

```
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager MyNavigationManager
@code
{
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        MyNavigationManager.NavigateTo("route1");
    }
}
```

Learn more about navigationManager at [NavigationManager cheatsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53448294/842935)