# Do variable check only once in blazor

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I have several razor pages I want to do checks on using the current URL value.

They currently all have in their `@code{}` block URLs like:

```
Razor Page 1: MyNavigationManager.NavigateTo("sample_domain/sub_page_1?i=" + variable, forceLoad: true);
Razor Page 2: MyNavigationManager.NavigateTo("sample_domain/sub_page_2?i=" + variable, forceLoad: true); 
Razor Page 3: MyNavigationManager.NavigateTo("sample_domain/sub_page_3?i=" + variable, forceLoad: true);
```

I would like to remove the `sample_domain/` part if the URL has localhost in it.

So I have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50102726/get-current-url-in-a-blazor-component)  that I can get the current urls by Injecting before using it on .razor pages `@inject NavigationManager MyNavigationManager` and using `MyNavigationManager.Uri` to get the url.

Now I implemented it doing the following in each of the razor pages code block:

```
//check if the url has localhost
string domain_url = MyNavigationManager.Uri.ToString().Contains("localhost") ? "" : "/sample_domain";
MyNavigationManager.NavigateTo($"{domain_url}/sub_page_1?i=" + variable, forceLoad: true);
```

But now I only want to do the check once, and set the variable there, e.g. the `domain_url`. Then use that variable in the different razor pages without explicitly checking and setting it in each page. Maybe something like a global variable? session? But not sure how to go about that? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is stopping you from having a class in your project with a static field that you could reference in Razor pages? I suppose there are better ways than this one, but should work. Are you using Blazor Server or Blazor Webassembly?

Comment: Okay, would I be able to access the `NavigationManager` in the class? If so I think that might work for me. I am using Blazor Server

Answer (score 2):

You can call a method in a service to do that for you. For example, create a service `MyService.cs`, and have a method like `GetUrl`

```
public string GetUrl(string nav_url)
{
    return nav_url.ToString().Contains("localhost") ? "" : "/sample_domain";
}
```

Inject the service `@inject MyService MService` in `_Imports.razor`, also add the service in the Program.cs file `builder.Services.AddSingleton<MyService>();` then call the method like:

```
MyNavigationManager.NavigateTo($"{MService.GetUrl(MyNavigationManager.Uri)}/sub_page_1?i=" + variable, forceLoad: true);
```