# Get URL Params from route, without specifing @page route - Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

My component wants to access the route param `Foo` from the url `www.url.com/test?Foo=bar`. However, my component does not specify the @page "..." at the top of the `.razor` file.

I've tried accessing the param as following, without any success:

```cs
[SupplyParameterFromQuery]
public string? Foo{ get; set; }

...

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Foo); //outputs a blank line
    }
    ...
}
```

I am not sure, if the @page is the limitation, as I've read in some posts that this fixed the problem of others. Surely there must be a way to acess the url-param.

Comment: The parameters are passed to the Route component;  they aren't automatically cascaded. You can access the Url by injecting the Navigation Manager, or create a cascading value to pass the values down.

Comment: blazor component without `@page`  reminds me of the child component, as the child component is designed to use inside the parent component which should have the route. In this scenario we could follow @MrC's idea to use the cascading parameter or try to get the url parameter in the parent component then pass it to the child component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MyNavigationManager`:

```
@inject NavigationManager MyNavigationManager


...

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetQueryParm("Foo")); //outputs a blank line
    }
    ...
}

string GetQueryParm(string parmName)
{
    var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(MyNavigationManager.Uri);
    var q = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
    return q[parmName] ?? "";
}
```

Credits to myself: [NavigationManager - Get current URL in a Blazor component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50102726/navigationmanager-get-current-url-in-a-blazor-component)

Comment: Works like a charm - thanks!